# Overcoming the invalid use of hooks error using a given framework component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having some trouble importing and using a framework I would like within my JS app. When I import and include this component within a page function for my site, I get a slew of errors saying I have "Invalid hook call"s. I have run through the recommended checks to determine whether I have duplicate reacts within my project:

`npm ls react-dom`

```
└─┬ react-select@5.7.0
  ├── react-dom@18.2.0
  └─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
    └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
```

`npm ls react`

```
├─┬ @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0
├─┬ multiselect-react-dropdown@2.0.25
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└─┬ react-select@5.7.0
  ├─┬ @emotion/react@11.10.5
  │ ├─┬ @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.0
  │ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └─┬ use-isomorphic-layout-effect@1.1.2
    └── react@18.2.0 deduped
```

It seems I'm fine on this front. Here is the code I'm using to include and use a framework for a dropdown select (open to suggestions on how to get the data from a multiselect dropdown also - using setPractices):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const FormPage = () => {
    const [ practices, setPractices ] = useState([])

    const NZoptions = [
        { value: 'restructuring', label: 'Restructuring and Insolvency' },
        { value: 'mergers', label: 'Mergers and Acquisitions' },
        { value: 'banking', label: 'Banking and Finance' }
    ]

    return (
        <section className="form-section">
                <div className="form-input multi">
                    <label>Practices:</label>
                        <Select
                            defaultValue={[ NZoptions[0], NZoptions[1] ]}
                            isMulti
                            name="practices"
                            options={ NZoptions }
                            className="basic-multi-select"
                            classNamePrefix="select"
                        />
                </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

When I run this code on the frontend of my webapp, I'm still getting errors within the browser console notifying me of the following:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It's worth noting a few things here:

- I have used code prescribed by the [React Select documentation](https://react-select.com/home) to implement this selection component
- This error occurs for any framework I attempt to import
- The error does not disappear if I remove the `useState` from the module

Comment: You don't have a lot of duplicates, they're explicitly `deduped`.

Comment: Indeed. You should share the code of this component as it could be for a number of other reasons beyond mismatching versions.

Comment: And if you remove that `useState` the error goes away?

Comment: OP: No, if I remove `useState` the error remains.